# service httpd status shows Internal Server Error

Tags: apache

I have a dedicated server. No PHP files were running when i use my website so i tried looking into the apache and used "service httpd status" to check apache status and this is what i am getting

## service httpd status

```
                         Internal Server Error
```

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
   unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, root@mps-vm1 and inform them
   of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that
   may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error
   log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
     **______________________________________________________________**

```
Apache/2.2.27 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.27 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips
mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at localhost Port 80
```

Can someone please tell me what should i do?

Comment: Perhaps this question belongs to serverfault.com...

Comment: please ask this question in unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Check `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log`